# Do we need guru or diksha to do bhakti or nama japa for certain forms? For example, Matangi?

Tags: bhakti, nama-japa, ishta-devta

I have heard that one cannot worship Matangi without guru and initiation. I have heard similar things about other forms, for example other tantric deities. My question is, does this apply also to bhakti, nama japa, and selecting a form as your ishta? For example, could one worship Matangi with bhakti and nama japa in a right hand sort of way, only for the purpose of worshiping her/moksha, and not need guru and initiation to do so? Or would one need guru and initiation before one can even have bhakti towards forms like these?

I have no interest in Tantra or the left hand path practices as such, and I have no concern for material gain or supernatural powers. My question is purely a bhakti and devotional sort of inquiry.